# Random Multiple date Selection in xdsoft datetimepciker plugin

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I have used xdsoft datetime picker for my web application and it is excellent and perfectly working. But need to select random date (no range) like 2016/09/21,2016/09/21 here two random date which i want to select by datepicker at a time like input box of datebox will contain two dates at a time. it can be 2016/09/21,2016/09/25,2016/09/30.But only one date i can pick at a time. How can i do this by xdsoft datetimepicker? My code is below

```
<input type="text" id="datebox"/>
 $("#datebox").datetimepicker({
                    format: format_string,
                    timepicker: time_option,

});
```

I need my output like the following:

[image]

Can do this by xdsoft datepicker plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use events like onSelectTime, onChangeMonth, onChangeYear, onChangeDateTime. You can find more options and features in http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/. For example

```
var dateValues = [];
$("#datebox").datetimepicker({
    format: format_string,
    timepicker: time_option,
    onChangeDateTime: function(current_date_time) {
        if (dateValues.length === 2) {
            dateValues = [];
        }
        var pickedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate(format_string, current_date_time);
        dateValues.push(pickedDate);
        $("#datebox").val(dateValues.join(','));
    }
});
```